# Adding new checkbox field to tx_news_domain_model_media

Tags: typo3, extbase, tx-news

I am trying to add a new checkbox field 'showinhome' to the table 'tx_news_domain_model_media' same to the field 'showinpreview' here is my TCA Configuration in Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tx_news_domain_model_media.php

```
$temporaryColumns = [
    'showinhome' => [
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label'   => 'Show in Home',
        'config'  => [
            'type'    => 'check',
            'default' => 0,
        ],
    ],
];

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns(
    'tx_news_domain_model_media',
    $temporaryColumns
);
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_news_domain_model_media']['ctrl']['label_alt'] .= ', showinhome';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_news_domain_model_media']['interface']['showRecordFieldList'] .= ', showinhome';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_news_domain_model_media']['palettes']['newsPalette']['showitem'] .= 'showinhome,';
```

The field is not displayed, can someone help me please?

Comment: should not the last line have the comma before the field name? `$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_news_domain_model_media']['palettes']['newsPalette']['showitem'] .= ',showinhome';`

Comment: $TCA['tx_news_domain_model_media']['palettes']['palettteCore']['showitem'] = 'type,showinpreview, hidden,sys_language_uid, l10n_parent, l10n_diffsource,showinhome,';                                                it appears in the configuration so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed up some stuff here.

First: tx_news can use either the own media model or the native FAL relations. I personally always use the native FAL relation.

If you want to add this field to the media table, then there is no `newsPalette` there. You can use the below code to add the new field:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('tx_news_domain_model_media', $temporaryColumns);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('tx_news_domain_model_media', implode(',', array_keys($temporaryColumns)));
```

If you using the normal FAL relation then the `showinpreview` field is added to the `sys_file_reference` table's TCA configuration and not to the `tx_news_domain_model_media` table.

If you want to add this field to the file, then you need to add it to the `sys_file_reference` field the same way tx_news does it (I guess that you already copied the code from it's override file)

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('sys_file_reference', $temporaryColumns);

// add special news palette
$GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_file_reference']['palettes']['newsPalette']['showitem'] .= ', showinhome';
```

Last but not least: you have to specify tx_news as a dependency in your extension, otherwise TYPO3 does not know that your extension has to be loaded after tx_news. If you change the dependency after you installed your extension you probably need to uninstall and install it again in the extension manager.

Comment: Thanks for the answer when I add the Configuration in ext_tables.php the field will be displayed but in Confifuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_file_reference.php not. I d'ont know why.